# Wie kann man 気持ちいい am besten auf Deutsch ausdrücken?

Tags: translation, single-word-request, japanese

Wie kann man das Japanische 気持ちいい *kimochi ii* am besten auf Deutsch ausdrücken in den folgenden Situationen:

- ein *kimochi ii* Pullover
- eine *kimochi ii* Massage
- *kimochi ii* Wetter
- generell *kimochi ii*, *chōshi ii*

Es scheint, daß das Wort schwer mit einem einzelnen deutschen Wort zu übersetzen ist.

> ドイツ語でこんな時に何と言いますか？
>
> - 気持ちいい服
> - マッサージが気持ちいい
> - 天気が気持ちいい
> - 調子がいい、気持ちいい

---

*[気持ちいい](http://wadoku.de/wadoku/search/%E6%B0%97%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E3%81%84%E3%81%84) heißt wörtlich "Gefühl gut", oder "gutes Gefühl".*

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close as off-topic before I realised that the description allowed translations from _any_ language, and now I can't figure out how to remove that close-vote.

Comment: Please also see http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/1406/should-translation-questions-be-bounded-to-german-english

Comment: @deceze Thanks. "Angenehm" will work, but from your translation I guess that it is too weak, so maybe "sehr angenehm".

Comment: @thei Exactly, the exact nuance is hard to get. Hence the question. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Meine Vorschläge, wenn es darum geht, kimochi ii immer mit dem gleichen Begriff zu übersetzen wären:

- Wohlfühlpullover
- Wohlfühlmassage
- Wohlfühlwetter

Es kann sein, dass diese regionabhängig unterschiedlich verbreitet sind, zumindest die Wohlfühlmassage liest man hier (Hamburg) relativ häufig in der Werbung.

Comment: +1 für "Wohlfühlmassage", obwohl das schon ganz schön hartes Werbedeutsch ist. ;-) "Wohlfühlpullover" klingt noch okay, aber "Wohlfühlwetter" geht gar nicht.

Comment: Danke für das +1 ... wegen dem Wohlfühlwetter: einfach mal den Wetterbericht auf den Privatsendern verfolgen ... ich weiß es ist traurig, aber dahin wächst die deutsche Sprache.

Comment: Autsch, jetzt weiß ich wieder, warum ich kein Fernesehen schaue. ^^ Aber eigentlich sollten wir uns freuen, dass sie es nicht "wellnesswetter" nennen. :)

Comment: Ja, das stimmt wohl. Für mich sind alle drei Begriffe "Werbesprache" oder zumindest über diesen Weg entstanden. Wenn man das vermeiden will, würde ich gemütlich oder angenehm als Adjektiv verwenden.

Comment: stimme @ladybug zu und kann das für den Salzburger Sprachraum auch bestätigen

Answer (score 5):

> das Wort […] mit einem einzelnen deutschen Wort […] übersetzen

Ich denke darin liegt der Fehler. Es gibt viele Ausdrücke, insbesondere (nach eigener Erfahrung) aus dem Japanischen, die einfach nicht direkt übersetzbar sind. Vor allem eben nicht mit einem einzigen Wort.

Selbst wenn man auf der schweren Suche ein passendes Wort findet, so wird dies meistens ein ziemlich seltenes Wort sein, sodass man zwar die Bedeutung gut trifft, aber nicht wirklich etwas „Deutsches“ da stehen hat. Von daher sollte man bei solchen Übersetzungen immer versuchen den Sinn zu treffen, nicht aber wörtlich eine Entsprechung suchen.

Beispielsweise wäre ein „sich gut anfühlender Pullover“ nach meinem Verständnis absolut korrekt, und ja, ich würde es so auch selbst sagen.

Comment: Stimmt ja, daß man eher den Sinn wiedergeben muss als das Wort. Wie würdest Du denn die Beispiele auf Deutsch übersetzen?

Comment: Entweder auch mit „sich gut anfühlend“ oder auch einfach mit „angenehm“. Insbesondere beim Wetter würde ich vermutlich eher das letzte sagen. Bei den ersten beiden würde man eher, je nachdem wie man es sagen möchte, den direkten Zusammenhang auseinander brechen und beispielsweise sagen: „Die Massage fühlt sich gut an“, oder so ähnlich.

Comment: Bei Pullover muss ich sofort an "kuschelig" denken. Das Konzept von  kimochi ii Wetter gibt es glaub ich gar nicht in Deutschland, daher kann man das wohl wirklich nur mit "angenehm" wiedergeben.

Answer (score 1):

Solche kleinen Worte haben mir den Japanischunterricht immer schwer gemacht. `kimochi ii Wetter` würde ich vielleicht mit ,,schönes Wetter'' oder ,,schöner Sommertag'' übersetzen. Der Pullover könnte ein ,,Wohlfühlpullover'' sein. Massagen sind nicht so mein Ding und generell ... naja ... gibt es im Japanischen überhaupt Worte, die man ohne Kontext richtig übersetzen kann?

MfG

Comment: Hmm... *"schönes Wetter"* ist nicht unbedingt das Selbe wie 「気持ちいい天気」... Es drückt ja mehr ein persönliches Gefühl des Wohlseins aus.

Comment: richtig. deshalb auch der Übersetzungsversuch mit "schöner Sommertag". Vll noch "himmlisches Wetter" aber das klingt auch irgendwie doof ...

Comment: Könnte man das Wetter und die Massage nicht auch mit Wohlfühl... übersetzen? Begriffe wie Wohlfühlwetter und Wohlfühlmassage sind m.E. durchaus gebräuchlich. Oder trifft das nicht die Bedeutung von kimochi ii?

Comment: @Hinek: Klingt für mich zwar ein wenig komisch aber die Bedeutung trifft es recht gut, denke ich.

Comment: "schöner Sommertag" aber nur, wenn jemand Sommer mag (ja, die Minderheit der Sommer-Nicht-Möger (ich will mal nicht -Hasser schreiben ;-)) existiert)

Comment: @jae: Richtig! 'kimochi ii' drückt ein persönliches Wohlempfinden aus und damit ist es SEHR schwer eine Übersetzung dafür zu finden

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe sofort an

> gemütlich

gedacht. Da es diesen Vorschlag bisher nur im Kommentar von @Hinek gibt, erlaube ich mir, es als Antwort vorzuschlagen.